# Migrate SharePoint 2013 from windows server 2008 to 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, migration

We got a requirement to migrate sharepoint 2013 servers from windows server 2008 to NEW windows server 2012.
WE have one app server and one db server.
Both servers have to be upgraded.
We have workflows,customisations in master page and web.config files.
Can someone give step by step implementation of the same, including the powershell commands.
I am fairly new to sharepoint administration.

Comment: what patch level of SharePoint 2013 and which OS you want to migrate?

Answer (score 1):

this is not an easy task, If you have one extra server then it will be easy.

- Install SharePoint on new server, Apply customization, update the web.config
- Join the server to the farm, now move all the service application and DNS to this server. Test it
- Now remove the old server from farm, uninstall sharepoint, upgrade the OS then re install the SharePoint and apply all customization and other changes.
- Test it. Now remove the 2nd server from farm. At this point you have your SharePoint server updgraded.

Otherwise here are the [official guideline from MSFT.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2818510/how-to-upgrade-a-server-operating-system-that-has-sharepoint-server-20)

To perform a full-version operating system upgrade on a SharePoint Server 2010 or SharePoint Server 2013 server, follow these steps:

1. Make sure that the intended operating system is supported by the
   version of SharePoint that you are running.
2. Detach the content databases from the SharePoint server.
3. Uninstall SharePoint through Control Panel.
4. Upgrade the operating system.
5. Reinstall SharePoint.
6. Configure all web applications, update web.config files, deploy customizations. Create and configure all service applications.
7. Attach the content databases.

Comment: we have another new server to which we want to migrate.my concern is existing sharepoint application is running in windows server 2008, we want to mov it to new server which is on windows server 2012.can we use backup and restore commands in powershell for this?

Comment: in that case, you can install SharePoint on windows 2012 server (smae patch level) then join that server to exisitng farm. once it is part of farm move all services and web application to new server. once done then remove old server from farm.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.can u plz elaborate on the above , the steps in detail to add to existing farm, moving services n web app to new server,; (links to documents with these information would be really helpful )